# Click Button on Website with scheduled script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a website with external like buttons (from likebtn.com) on it. 
 To encourage users to use them I have a script that randomly gives likes to random posts. However I have the problem that this could only be done via the REST API from likebtn.com if the post already has min 1 Like from a button click.
 It is not possible for me to send an API request to achieve this (as told by likebtn.com support).
My question now is:
Is it possible (with javascript) to run a cron that opens the url with the post and clicks the like button once?
Any help or tips are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly but you could do something like this.
Run this code from a cronjob on set intervals.  It simulates the click of the like button on page load.

[http://jsfiddle.net/m3gN2/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/m3gN2/)

```
<?php ?>
<button id="virtualLike">Like Me!</button>

<script>

var likeBtn = document.getElementById('virtualLike');   // get a reference to your element
likeBrn.onclick = clickHandler; // assign its click function a function reference

function clickHandler() {
alert("Button is clicked");
}
document.getElementById('virtualLike').click();

</script>

<?php ?>
```

Let me know if it was what you wanted and if it works for you.

Comment: Hi, yes you understood exactly what I wanted thanks! I will try this as soon as I get the chance and will report if everything worked!

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you very much! I would upvote your answer but I don't have enough reputation sadly.